# Toggling words in divs on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, toggle

please see this http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/bJxaL/

I have 7 audio tracks that I need to play and pause when the user clicks on their divs. So far I have a very long winded bit of code that does this. However, I am trying to toggle the title and the word pause on the div when it is clicked and I do not know how to make the title toggle back when one clicks on a different div from the one playing?

If you look at the fiddle and click on one div then click on another the audio will pause on the first div you click on and play the second audio but the first div still displays 'pause', I need it to then display the song title again.

Here is a snippet of the code, but please look at the fiddle to see it all

```
 $("#one").click(function () {
 if ($('#sound-1').get(0).paused == false) {
    $('#sound-1').get(0).pause();
 } else {
    $('#sound-1').get(0).play();
   }
 $('#one i').toggle();
$('#sound-2').get(0).pause();
$('#sound-3').get(0).pause();
$('#sound-4').get(0).pause();
$('#sound-5').get(0).pause();
$('#sound-6').get(0).pause();
$('#sound-7').get(0).pause();
});
$("#two").click(function () {
 if ($('#sound-2').get(0).paused == false) {
    $('#sound-2').get(0).pause();
 } else {
    $('#sound-2').get(0).play();
   }
 $('#two i').toggle();
$('#sound-1').get(0).pause();
$('#sound-3').get(0).pause();
$('#sound-4').get(0).pause();
$('#sound-5').get(0).pause();
$('#sound-6').get(0).pause();
$('#sound-7').get(0).pause();
});
```

Comment: You should look at using `.each`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i managed to get it to work with the following code :

```
var $bars = $('.bars');
var pauseWord = 'pause'; // Because I've got rid of <i>pause</i> things

$bars.each(function () {
    // Save songtitle in data attribute
    $(this).data('title', $(this).find('i').text());
});

$bars.click(function () {
    // Work on the selected audio
    var songNumber = $(this).attr('id').replace('song-', '');
    var sound = $('#sound-' + songNumber).get(0);
    if(sound.paused){
        sound.play();
        $(this).find('i').html(pauseWord);
    } else {
        sound.pause();
        $(this).find('i').html($(this).data('title'));
    }
    // Set other bars to its default state and pause other audios
    $bars.not(this).each(function(){
        $(this).find('i').html($(this).data('title'));
        $('#sound-' + $(this).attr('id').replace('song-', '')).get(0).pause();
    });
});
```

By the way, i changed few things in your HTML as well (the bars id and the pause) :

```
<div id="song-1" class="bars">
    <div class="songtitle"><i class="play">I tried to tell you</i>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="song-2" class="bars">
    <div class="songtitle"><i class="play">Intro</i>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="song-3" class="bars">
    <div class="songtitle"><i class="play">Vocal</i>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="song-4" class="bars">
    <div class="songtitle"><i class="play">Can</i>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="song-5" class="bars">
    <div class="songtitle"><i class="play">Confusion</i>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="song-6" class="bars">
    <div class="songtitle"><i class="play">i</i>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="song-7" class="bars">
    <div class="songtitle"><i class="play">My Heart</i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JSFiddle updated : http://jsfiddle.net/Oliboy50/bJxaL/39/

Answer (score 2):

Here...just scrap all your js for this...and you can even work to simplify your mark-up if you don't actually need the 2 separate  elements in each bar.

http://jsfiddle.net/beauxjames/bJxaL/3/

```
function toggleTheWorld(e) {

    var bars = $("#sound-bars .bars"),
        $thisBar = $(e.currentTarget);

    $.each(bars, function(index, bar) {
        var iPlay = $(bar).find('.play'),
            iStop = $(bar).find('.stop');
        if( $thisBar.attr('id') == $(bar).attr('id') ) {
            iPlay.toggle(false);
            iStop.toggle(true);
        } else {
            iPlay.toggle(true);
            iStop.toggle(false);
        }

    });
}

$("#sound-bars .bars").click(toggleTheWorld);
```

A couple things to note.

1. you just needed to make the operation generic
2. there is just one function
3. there is one line that binds this function to the click event of each bar...automatically providing 'e' as an event parameter in the function and will always be relative to the event
4. $.each will loop through the whole collection
5. we compare each bar to the bar that originated the event and do what we need to do on both a match and a !match

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really was needing to simplify, but I also need the audio to pause when one clicks on the same bar again. Also I can not hear the audios on click?

Comment: you can put in any function you want for the audio to trigger...that was the whole point of me breaking it down the way I did...just put your logic into the appropriate section in the $.each block